# Auto populate column by reference?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on the following sheet, called `Raw_Data`:

[image]

In a new sheet, I want to copy the `registration_date` column by reference. This means that if I change the registration_date on the `Raw_Data`, the changed value should be reflected in the new sheet.

To implement this, I have entered the following `=Raw_Data!C2`. So far it works fine as you can see below:

[image]

But the problem is that when I double click on the little green square here, it doesn't automatically populate the entire column.

[image]

I don't want to manually drag-and-drop because there are several thousand rows. Does anyone know how I could automatically populate the column by reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are some automation things you could do, I think a lot of that would be overkill for what could be just an input issue with how you are choosing to copy in Excel.

If you find that you need to copy a large block of data, rather than dragging the corner of your cell like that, try one of these alternate methods:

While selected on the cell, press CNTRL + C. Then in the 'Name Box' (where it shows the address of the cell you are on), type in the cell where you want to go (A17000); then press SHIFT + ENTER. This will jump you to that cell, and will highlight all cells inbetween where you were and where you are going. Then press CNTRL + V.

Another method of moving around a large data block in Excel is to hold CNTRL and press an arrow key. This will move you as far down the data block as possible. Note that this will not work on a blank sheet, as there is no data and therefore Excel doesn't know when to stop.

Again - some automation would be possible here, but moving around an Excel worksheet is something you will be doing too frequently in too many different ways to want to automate what might be 5 keystrokes once a week.

Comment: Thanks for these inputs. I think CNTRL + C and typing in the cell (for ex: A17000) where I want to go is a good idea. However, because my report size will vary every week, I am still hoping to find a permanent and generic solution where Excel auto-decides how many cells to use, rather than I having to manually see how many rows my report contains and then copy only upto that row. But I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Again, automation is likely not the key here - learning to navigate Excel quickly will save you far more time in the long run that eliminating 5 keystrokes a week. Another option, as suggested by @Amit, is to copy your column from your raw data sheet. Select the first cell there, hold SHIFT + CNTRL + DOWN, press CNTRL C, and go to your other tab and press CNTRL V. Then on your new tab, you can type your formula on A1, CNTRL C, SHIFT + CNTRL + DOWN, then CNTRL V.

Comment: One final tip - if this is a report that you are creating every week, how do you 'roll-forward' the old one? I recommend you save last week's report as a new file with the new date. Then when you paste in your raw data most of your work will already be done, you will just need to adjust how many rows are copied. This especially applies if you are doing any other manipulation to the workbook; you could save a lot of time by rolling forward files from week to week.

Comment: Yep. Makes sense. This is exactly what I will do now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In excel the "double click to fill" feature is a heuristic based feature that fills the cells that appear to be relevant with the selected formula (+ reference corrections).

In your case there is no hint the heuristic can use to tell what to fill so nothing is being done.

Regarding dragging "several thousand rows", that's not a real problem. If you only do it once, there no reason to even trying anything "smart" or complicated.

You can also copy the source cell, select all the cells you want to fill and then paste. You can select cells in any way you like, not just dragging.

You could instead of all the dragging/copying/filling approach simply copy directly from the source, and paste by reference.

As a last resort, you can always go for a VBA solution to do that for you.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't solve my problem. I can't drag around 17,000 rows. Moreover, these reports will be generated weekly, so I am looking for a generic solution.